# Characters disappear from my shell variables when they are echoed

Tags: macos, bash

This is driving me absolutely crazy:

```
$ a="/"
echo $a  # note empty output line below

$ var="/home/vivek/foo/bar"
$ echo $var
home vivek foo bar
```

What's going on in my `bash` shell on OS X?

I've tried this on my other Mac.. and it works perfectly!

Comment: Cross-posted on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/987839/forward-slash-disappear-into-a-variable-in-osx

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr:**

Reset the special `$IFS` variable to its default - `IFS=$' \t\n'` - or, preferably, *double-quote* your variable reference (`echo "$var"`) to print the value *as-is*.

---

You're referencing `$var` *unquoted*, which means that its value is subject to *word splitting* (one of the [many expansions that Bash applies to unquoted tokens](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)).

Word splitting happens by any of the characters defined in the built-in `$IFS` variable (the Internal Field Separator), which defaults to `$' \t\n'` (space, tab, newline).

In your case, `$IFS` contains `/` (possibly among other chars.), which means that `/home/vivek/foo/bar` is split into *separate arguments* `home`, `vivek`, `foo`, `bar`, which are then passed to `echo`.

`echo`, when given multiple arguments, prints them separated with a space, which is what you're seeing.

(Similarly, `/` as the value of `$var` is interpreted as *just* a separator, with *no* fields, which means that no arguments are passed to `echo`, which just prints a newline).

---

There are 2 lessons here:

- Only *temporarily* change `$IFS`; restore the previous value once you're done with the custom value.
- Generally, *double-quote all variable references* to ensure that their values are preserved as-is; only use *unquoted* variable references if you explicitly *want* shell expansions applied to their values.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I forgot completely IFS=$' \t\n'. Thanks a lot